# Why does the String(_:radix:) initializer work?

Tags: swift

I came across this `String` extension in a project that I'm dissecting and cannot figure out why the `String` initializer on line `3` works.

```
fileprivate extension String {
    init(integer n: Int, radix: Int, padding: Int) {
        let s = String(n, radix: radix)
        let pad = (padding - s.count % padding) % padding
        self = Array(repeating: "0", count: pad).joined(separator: "") + s  
    }
}
```

`let s = String(n, radix: radix)`

Here is the initializer in the documentation:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997127-init

But the signature of that init is `init(_:radix:uppercase:)`. Yet, the example at the bottom of the page uses the `init(_:radix:)` signature. How is this possible?

Comment: @MartinR I saw that but if an initializer has a default value, Swift allows you to just omit the parameter from the initializer? I wasn't aware this was a rule.

Comment: @MartinR but signatures play an important role in type safety. If this were part of a protocol, wouldn't it consider this different and not conforming?

Comment: Sorry, I do not yet see how that affects type safety or protocol conformance. (Perhaps you want to ask a new question about that, with a concrete example?)

Comment: Why the downvote? What am I missing about this place that this question is not considered acceptable? Annoying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A “Jump to Definition” in Xcode reveals that the method is declared as

```
public init<T>(_ value: T, radix: Int = 10, uppercase: Bool = false) where T : BinaryInteger
```

i.e. the `uppercase` parameter has a [default parameter value](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID169):

> You can define a default value for any parameter in a function by assigning a value to the parameter after that parameter’s type. If a default value is defined, you can omit that parameter when calling the function.

Here the default value is `false`, so that

```
let s = String(n, radix: radix)
```

is equivalent to calling

```
let s = String(n, radix: radix, uppercase: false)
```